# Should I immediately answer questions that I post to prevent them being downvoted and closed because they are too broad?

Tags: discussion

I noticed some holes in the MSE knowledgebase and posted  questions to fill those holes:

- [How do you construct triad superimpositions in the style of Steve Khan?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/85706/how-do-you-construct-triad-superimpositions-in-the-style-of-steve-khan)
- [What is Pat Martino's Diminished Concept?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/85704/what-is-pat-martinos-diminished-concept)
- [What is Pat Martino's Minor Conversion Concept?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/85705/what-is-pat-martinos-minor-conversion-concept)

All three of these questions are about to be closed for being "too broad."  Even though they can each be answered in a handful of paragraphs.

I waited for others to answer because I know reputation is very important to other people and I wanted to give them the chance to gain rep by posting an answer that I would appreciate the insights of.  And others on the site frequently have insights that I've missed.

Should I instead immediately post answers to questions I ask like this to prevent them from being closed?  If they are closed, I don't really see the point in answering them.

Comment: If you plan to self-answer, then I would do so immediately, to make your intentions clear. You can wait a few days before accepting your own answer, to give people a chance to post a possibly better answer.

Answer (score 8):

> I waited for others to answer because, well, rep.

Then you are posting these questions for the wrong reasons. If you genuinely want to share knowledge by asking questions you actually face and can answer yourself, just go ahead and answer them. Teasing at answers in the comments like it's social media clickbait ("If this tweet gets 500 likes...") makes you look a lot less genuine and I'm not surprised people are reacting to that negatively.

The fact that your questions are all about methods named after individuals doesn't help, because the site has suffered in the past from people who think it's an appropriate place to plug their pet favourite teaching method. People have used questions that sound like yours as a launch pad to write what is essentially a blog post explaining why everyone should use their teaching method or practice. That kind of behaviour is pretty unwelcome. If you're going to write questions that look like that, people are going to be extra cautious about whether these are genuine questions that you really face, so it's a bad time to be doing things that make you look less genuine.

If your questions and answers are really useful, and you're more interested in sharing knowledge than in the rep, go ahead and self-answer immediately. If they really are useful to people, they'll get upvoted in the end.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It helps refine my participation in this community. It's too late for these questions as they are about to closed, but I'll consider it in the future if I think I have something to share.

Comment: I waited for others to answer because I know reputation is very important to other people and I wanted to give them the chance to gain wrapping post an answer that I would appreciate the insights of..  And others on the site frequently have insights that I've missed.

Comment: people who answer their own questions don't get any increasing reputation except for marking an answer answered which is true if somebody else answered it. Google's stackoverflow sock puppets for an explanation.

Comment: @pro If people vote up your question or answer, you get the same reputation as you do from other questions and answers. You only don't get reputation if nobody thought your self-answered question was useful.

Comment: Per Diamond @Dom he sometimes answers immediately and sometimes waits for the community https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2594/10635

Comment: @pro I want to point out that there's a difference between once in a while asking a general question many can answer that the site needs and asking a very specific question with a very specific answer you had in mind. The former being a good way to get the community's perspective on something you already have an idea of, the later being one of the cases you should answer up front.  You've also asked 6 of these types of questions within 2 days on very similar topics which I think raised some red flags in the community.

Comment: @dom I freely admit that I don't understand this community very well at all. Despite being in the top 3% of reputation. At this moment I'm trying to understand how a question can be very specific and yet closed for being overly broad.

Comment: @pro My theory is that the concepts you mentioned were so specific as to turn others away from trying to answer (I, for one, read "Pat Martino's Diminished Concept" and thought to myself, *"What's that? I'd better leave this one to the specialists"*). The "Too Broad" might have been just because asking for a whole concept explained might have set off some *"What?! I'm not explaining a whole entire concept! I'm too old for that!"*, triggering close votes.

Comment: I'm glad you are coming to Meta about this; the fact that you're trying to help solve the problem lends you some major street cred with me. If I were in your shoes, the only thing I'd do differently would be to self-answer immediately, just because if I already knew the best answer for something specific like that, I'd just throw my answer in there, and if someone has something to add to the discussion, they could post their own answer too.

Comment: I might also have been a little more explicit in the question itself, but that's minor. I've done the odd [self-answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/72062/45266) myself, and in that one in particular I literally didn't have an answer at the time I wrote the question, so that might be another way self-answers factor into the site. But in general, providing information in the form of self-answers is an admirable cause, but if there's really one answer that you're looking for as "correct", then I'd advise just posting it immediately (waiting to accept, however, is a nice touch as well).

Comment: @user45266 I've come around to that point of view. I'm only active on the site in bursts. And I've done my share of theory and performance so questions I'm going to are going to tend to be fairly technical or esoteric. If I have the answer I'll provide it. I've just been holding back out of an apparently misplaced sense of fair play.

Comment: Although, looking at my history, there have been a number of self answers that I really did not have a clue what the answer was until I researched it while waiting for an answer.